# Solving first order differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am given this:

$$(2x+1)\frac{dy}{dx}+y = 0$$

I tried this:
$$\frac{1}{(2x+1)} dx = \frac{-1}{y} dy$$

Then integrated the above sum and got this:

$$ \frac{ln(2x+1)}{2}= -ln(y)$$

The answer is:  $y^2(2x+1) = C$.

I tried solving it by placing the like terms together and integrating them. However, my answer is wrong from the answer given.  Could you point out my mistake? Or am i evaluating the entire thing incorrectly?

All suggestions and help are appreciated!!! Thank you very much :)

Comment: You are almost done. Go to exponentials for both sides .. and don't forget the integration constant.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Oh god, i missed that part!!! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Note:I put in a dx in the second equation to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small error in what you did:

From $$\frac{dx}{2x+1}=-\frac{dy}{y},$$ you can conclude that (after integrating)
$$\frac{\ln(2x+1)}{2} + C = -\ln (y),$$
where $C$ is some constant (which you forgot).

Other than that, you got stuck at the easiest part. Once you have

$$\ln(2x+1) = -2\ln(y) + C,$$
you just need to get this into the form $\ln(something) = \ln(somethingelse)$ and then conclude that $something = somethingelse$.

Comment: Thank you, just realized that i missed the last step :)